# Copy values from original array into a new one

Tags: arrays, assembly, arm, keil

recently I'm learning assembly language and are using ARM assembler with Keil tool. And I came across some problems online. It requires some code to copy values from the sourcearray(listed below) and writes it to a destination array while also removing the duplicates. What I do not understand quite clear is how to copy the array? Hope someone can help..
EDIT: While I'm asking for help I'm also trying to figure it out on my own, but I would really appreciate someone giving me a example. And, this is NOT an assignment. It's just pure self-study.

```
SRAM_BASE   EQU     0x40000000; start of the address

            AREA    Reset, CODE, READONLY
            ENTRY





stop        B       stop

sourceArray       DCB   2,44,66,66,1,1,4,10,3,10,23,1,23,255,254,2,2,3
asize             DCB   (asize-sourceArray)     

    END
```

Comment: Do you know how to write a loop? Do you know how to read and write memory? Put the two together, and you got your copy :) To filter out duplicates a trivial method is to scan the output array to see if you already copied the element.

Comment: I do know how to write a loop but what command should I use for copying? By LDR everything from the old array and then send it to a new one? Not sure if it is correct tho.

Comment: Yes, use `LDRB`/`STRB` since you have bytes.

Comment: @Jester ok I'm working on it now... Do you mind check back later? Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: so there is one thing, if I want to loop I would need a loop counter but as the loop is progressing it will also remove the duplicates so will that affect the counter or it works just fine under that?

Comment: You still need to iterate over the full number of _input_ elements regardless of what you then do with them. Your output array index/pointer, on the other hand, is only going to change if you do actually add something to it.